# Python equivalent of Perl's idiom do this or that, usually known as "or die"?

Tags: python, perl, boolean, idioms, short-circuiting

IN Perl it's quite common to do things like `function() || alternative()`. If the first returns false it will run the second one.

How can this be easily implemented in Python?

**Update**

Examples (pseudocode):

```
x = func() or raise exeption
x = func() or print(x)
func() or print something
```

If possible solutions should work with Python 2.5+

Note: There is an implied assumption that you cannot modify the func() to raise exceptions, nor to write wrappers.

Comment: 80% of the time this is a terrible idea. In perl, this almost always depends on side effects that are implied or concealed in the functions.  Also, the Python equivalent only works if exceptions are ignored or silenced. Please provide your Python code where you'd like to use this.  It may be hiding more serious exception-handling issues.

Comment: While you can make it do this, we should point out that it's unusual in Python code. We usually use exceptions to handle unexpected situations.

Answer (score 5):

Use `or`: Python uses [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for boolean expressions:

```
function() or alternative()
```

If `function` returs True, the final value of this expression is determined and 
`alternative` is not evaluated at all.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `result = function() or print(result)` ?

Comment: You can do this in Python 3.X. In Python 2.X "print" is not a function but a statement. So if function() returns a value which evaluates to False, the result will be printed, and as print returns None, the value of "result" will be "None"

Comment: @rocksportrocker Considering the reference to `perl`, I suspect that what is wanted is something like `(result = function()) or (print(result))`  I don't think that Python allows these sorts of attrocities.

Comment: @JamesKanze: yes, this does not work in python as the assignment operation returns no value, as in Perl or C/C++

Comment: @rocksportrocker Or formulated more precisely: assignment is not an operator in Python.  The presence of an `=` in a Python statement means that it's an assignment statement, but what is to the left of the `=` isn't an expression, and an expression can't contain a `=`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `or`:

```
function() or alternative()
```

also, there is conditional expression defined in [PEP 308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/):

```
x = 5 if condition() else 0
```

Which is sometimes useful in expressions and bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
function() or alternative()
```

The mechanism is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

try with `or`:

```
>>> def bye():
  return 3

>>> print bye() or 342432
3
```

Unfortunately, this does not work like in Perl, because in Perl, after an assignment like `my $c = $d || 45;` you have in `$c` the value 45 if `$d` is undefined. In Python you get an error `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`